# Flutter Error. MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method ...)

Tags: flutter, kotlin

**My errors are below.**

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation 
               found for method getCurrentPosition on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator)

 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation 
              found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
```

I've searched several questions and know that I have to change MainActivity file.

I'm using kotlin in flutter so I want to know how to change MainActivity.kt file.
Or if anyone has another solution, please let me know.

Comment: Are you testing your app ? If not then first do `flutter  clean && flutter pub get`

Comment: I've done it several times, but error is happening.

Comment: Are you testing ? and show your MainActivity.kt file